# Is there a way to disable multi-line string literals in c++-mode?

Tags: font-lock, c++

Suppose I have a short string in C++ and I accidentally delete the double quote that ends it. What Emacs does is highlight the rest of the code as a single very long string, which messes up all the formatting until I put the double quote back in. It also feels a little slow when it's refontifying the whole buffer.

I skimmed through `cc-mode.el`, but I couldn't find the setting for it or the place where string fontification happens.

Is there a way to tell c++-mode (or font-lock maybe?) that my strings never contain newlines and it should never look beyond the first newline if it finds an unterminated string literal?

Comment: Do you use any syntax checkers? i.e like flycheck or flymake? They will show you the line with error, so it will be easy to correct.

Comment: @Ian Even if I know where the double quote is missing, it still makes the entire buffer after it look like a single long string. *That* is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to change this? The system is working as designed, giving you feedback that your code isn't correct.

Comment: @TrippLilley Yes: unfontifying and then refontifying the entire buffer after the string looks ugly and there is a noticeable UI lag too. Flycheck and lsp will always tell me about syntax errors anyway. Xcode, for example, highlights strings with a missing final quote only up to the next newline, and it looks much better to me that way.

Comment: I'm assuming this involves changing syntax tables as this mode might not do font locking itself.

Answer (score 1):

The function `c-literal-limits`, defined in `progmodes/cc-engine.el` determines how strings and comments are identified in all `c-mode` variants.  It uses these two definitions to do so:

```lisp
;; String syntax chars, suitable for skip-syntax-(forward|backward).
(defconst c-string-syntax (if (memq 'gen-string-delim c-emacs-features)
                              "\"|"
                            "\""))

;; Regexp matching string limit syntax.
(defconst c-string-limit-regexp (if (memq 'gen-string-delim c-emacs-features)
                                    "\\s\"\\|\\s|"
                                  "\\s\""))
```

Unfortunately, since this is not a configurable variable, you cannot just reassign it, and have `c-mode` do what you want it to do.  You would have to basically implement "advice" (see: `defadvice`) for the `c-literal-limits` function that uses your constants instead.  These constants would add an EOL (i.e., `"\\s$"`) to terminate the string expression.

This, of course, is not how the C/C++ *language* works, though, so I highly recommend not doing this, but the choice is yours, and as you can see, it's not an easy path.

Comment: It wasn't until C++0x that C++ had multi-line string literals. C doesn't have them at all AFAIK.

Comment: You are right.  I guess a better thing would be for Emacs to flag them as an error in non-C++ files.

Comment: Multi-line string literals in C++ have a special syntax introduced in C++11, they wouldn't necessarily appear like regular strings to emacs (e.g., `R""(string-contents)""`.

Comment: This works, but I don't want to "accept" this answer because it just seems so convoluted to have to advice/edit cc-engine.el just to get this feature. If I understood correctly, this only works for c-mode, which surprised me because I'd thought that identifying string literals was something done by emacs itself and then exposed through functions like `syntax-ppss`.

Comment: @Kirill "This works, but I don't want to "accept" this answer because it just seems so convoluted to have to advice/edit cc-engine.el just to get this feature" I hear ya.  The syntax engine in `c-mode` is not always flexible because it supports a lot of features, unfortunately...

Comment: @cyberbisson But thank you for figuring out how to make it work at all, I was completely stuck trying to do this on my own, I have it working in my emacs right now at least.

Comment: Given the other replies to my answer, perhaps your modification could be upstreamed into emacs.  Not everyone can claim to have helped write emacs!